# Finding amicable numbers in a given range using dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find amicable numbers in a given range using dictionaries in Python.

Here is my code and am unable to filter the dictionary items whose keys and values are amicable numbers. For example, in the output that I got after printing the  sum of proper divisors for each number from 1 to 1000, the items such as (220, 284), (284, 220) where 220 and 284 are amicable numbers. In this way I am trying to find all such amicable numbers in the range of 1 to 1000.

````
    index1 = 1
    index2 = 1000
    lst = []
    dict = {}
#     for i in range(index1, index2+1):
#         lst.append(i)

    print("Finding Amicable numbers..")
    for index in range(index1, index2+1):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(1, index):
            if index % i == 0:
                sum += i
            dict[index] = sum
        #print("Number = {}, Sum = {}".format(index, sum))
    print(dict.items())
    #print("k, v")
    #for k,v in dict.items():


    isAmicable2()

Output:
```Finding Amicable numbers..
dict_items([(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 1), (6, 6), (7, 1), (8, 7), (9, 4), (10, 8), (11, 1), (12, 16), (13, 1), (14, 10), (15, 9), (16, 15), ...................,(220, 284),(221, 31), (222, 234),..................,(280, 220)..........................................................................................(991, 1), (992, 1024), (993, 335), (994, 734), (995, 205), (996, 1356), (997, 1), (998, 502), (999, 521), (1000, 1340)])```


I have tried breaking the code into chunks and loop through but couldn't figure the way to do the same. 


    num1 = 220
    num2 = 284

    amicable1 = 0
    sum = 0
    for index1 in range(1, 220):
        if num1 % index1 == 0:
            sum += index1
        amicable1 = sum
    print(amicable1)

    amicable2 = 0
    sum2 = 0
    for index1 in range(1, 284):
        if num2 % index1 == 0:
            sum2 += index1
        amicable2 = sum2
    print(amicable2)

    if num1 == amicable2:
        print("{} and {} are amicable".format(num1, num2))

Expected results:
Print the pair of amicable numbers in a given range.
````

Comment: I think finding key value pairs where key of one pair is equal to the value of other and vice versa would solve my problem. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Here sum is not final value but just its a value for a particular key. All the values for each key are sums of proper divisors of each number.

Comment: Ok, it keeps setting the same entry each time through the loop, rather than once at the end.  You should still fix it, since all but the final assignment are dead and only serve to obfuscate and slow down your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already made a dictionary that contains the sum of the proper factors of a number you can just lookup a number and then lookup up the result of that lookup. In other words:

```
d = SomeDictWithSums

if d[d[n]] == n:
   # n is either amicable or a perfect number.
   # for example d[220] == 284 
   # and d[284] == 220
```

To weed out the perfect numbers just test for:

```
n != d[n]
```

You can put these two together in a pretty short bit of code to produce tuples of amicable numbers with something like:

```
index1 = 1
index2 = 1000
lst = []

print("Finding Amicable numbers..")
d = {}
for index in range(index1, index2+1):
    s = sum(i for i in range(1, index) if index % i == 0)
    d[index] = s

amicables = [(n, d[n]) for n in d if d[n] in d and d[d[n]] == n and n != d[n] ] 
print(amicables)
```

**Result**

```
Finding Amicable numbers..
[(220, 284), (284, 220)]
```

Remove the condition `and n != d[n]` will give you amicable and perfects:

```
[(6, 6), (28, 28), (220, 284), (284, 220), (496, 496)]
```

Comment: In the dictionary comprehension, can you please explain what is d[d[n]]? @Mark Meyer

Comment: @M06494h I tried in the first code block, maybe clearer with an explicit example. With amicable numbers `n == d[d[n]]` For example if `n` is `220`  then `d[220] == 284` and `d[284] == 220`. So you can substitute `284` for `d[220]`:   `d[d[220]] == d[284] == 220`.

Comment: Oh, got it. Now its clear. Thanks for your answer and reply. Great.